# Click in body and close Right-sided navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to find out a solution but everything i found it s useless. 
I have a menu in the right and a button "open". I just can t solve out how menu can automatically close when i click in the body. i found a lot of scripts on google but if i use them i can t click on menu.

this is how my menu looks like

[before i click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRVQc.png)

[after i click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLRf8.png)

everythin i tried will scratch up my code and will looks like in the first picture , but unclickable...

this is the CSS

```
.sidenavyt {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    opacity: 0.85;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}
#menu-close {
margin-top: -30px;
margin-right: 10px;
}
.sidenavyt a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenavyt a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenavyt .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenavyt {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenavyt a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

This is JS

```
function openNavyt() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenavyt").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("myNavBtn").style.opacity = "0";
}

function closeNavyt() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenavyt").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("myNavBtn").style.opacity = "1";
    document.body.addEventListener('click', fn, true); 
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="mySidenavyt" class="sidenavyt">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNavyt()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#Home">Home</a>
  <a href="#Produse">Produse</a>
  <a href="#Clienti">Clienti</a>
  <a href="#DespreNoi">Despre Noi</a>
  <a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
</div>
<div id="myNavBtn">
<span style=" position: fixed;z-index:1; top:0;right: 0;font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNavyt()">&#9776; open</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do like this

HTML

```
<div id="mySidenavyt" class="sidenavyt">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNavyt()">&times; 
</a>
<a href="#Home">Home</a>
<a href="#Produse">Produse</a>
<a href="#Clienti">Clienti</a>
<a href="#DespreNoi">Despre Noi</a>
<a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
</div>
<div id="myNavBtn">
<span style=" position: fixed;z-index:1; top:0;right: 0;font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNavyt()">&#9776; open</span>
</div>
<div id="backNav" style="width:100%;height:100%;display:none;position:absolute;z-index:1;background-color:red;" onclick="closeNavyt()">&nbsp;</div>
```

JS

```
    function openNavyt() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenavyt").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("myNavBtn").style.opacity = "0";
    document.getElementById("backNav").style.display = "initial";
}

function closeNavyt() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenavyt").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("myNavBtn").style.opacity = "1";
    document.getElementById("backNav").style.display = "none";
    document.body.addEventListener('click', fn, true);
}
```

Comment: well , it works , but when i open the menu , my carousel become a red image :-/ 

this is my carousel https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/full-slider/

Comment: Nevermind... i deleted "background-color:red;" 
thx a lot

Sth that i observed is that if i click on carousel it close. if i click on any other div it doesn t close. What should be the problem,?

Comment: Organize the containers in z-index. Put the carousel in the z-index: 1, the div backNav in z-index: 2 and the menu on top of everything in z-index: 3. The certain thing is that the menu stays in the z-index more above and the backNav just below the menu